# How to install TestNG plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng

I tried installing the testng plug-in for long time but eclipse is showing an error as below:

```
"No repository found as the location".
```

I have also tried to download and install the plug-in but the same error pops up.

Comment: Is it possible to install using pom in Maven?

Answer (score 13):

**Way 1:** For the Eclipse plug-in, we suggest using the update site:

1. Open Eclipse
2. Go to Help -> Install New Software...
3. Click Add button to go to Add Repository prompt
4. Enter Name as TestNG. In Location text box, enter the following URL -> Click Add button

http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/

5. Make sure the check box in the list is checked and click Next.
   Eclipse will then guide you through the process.

After installation follow the steps below:

1. Restart eclipse
2. Go to Window-> Preferences and observe the left panel
3. TestNG is enlisted

For Installation details visit the following site:

http://testng.org/doc/download.html

**Way 2:** TestNG can also be installed in Eclipse by using Marketplace. Below are the steps:

1. Open eclipse
2. Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...
3. Do search for TestNG (Type the text TestNG in Find text box > Click Go button)
4. After searching: Click Install button at TestNG for Eclipse area
5. Follow the further instructions by eclipse

Comment: @RiponAlWasim This answer could probably use an update, since Eclipse's interface has changed since then.

Comment: @jpaugh: yes, it might happened

Comment: Considering the basic thing go ahead with changing the eclipse interface

Comment: Is it possible to install using pom in Maven?

Comment: Just a side note, It would also be a good idea to keep your Marketplace Client up-to-date.

Note to [Giri] (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3506679/giri):
Yes the links from the official site has some kind of a problem,
was able to replicate and confirm your solution.

Also, why is this answer not accepted?
This is the correct answer.
OP please accept the proposed answer.

I know this is late, but we need to add these info for those who may come in later.

Comment: I tried doing the same with Eclipse 2019R06, Eclipse 2018-12, Oxygen etc versions, and all of them had the same problem, when at work. But my computer did not complain and installed perfectly. So, it is a proxy preventing it. When I disabled it, it is working perfectly. To figure this out, I need to waste so many hours. But it is my bad that, it has been mentioned in the troubleshooting guide though.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you misspelled the URL of the update site?

It's http://beust.com/eclipse

Comment: http://beust.com/eclipse is for Eclipse 3.4 and above. @Laloo: Which version of eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install from http://beust.com/eclipse and it won't work, delete spaces in the string :-)

Answer (score 1):

To install TestNG in Eclipse, follow the steps below :

1. Go to 'Help'
2. Click on 'Install New software'
3. Click on 'Add'
4. Enter Location - https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/

[image]

[image]

5. Click Next and Finish
6. Restart Eclipse.

Comment: The links within the link seem to be broken

Comment: @ArdentCoder: I am able to install TestNG using the link mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Copy the link http://beust.com/eclipse to notepad and copy from notepad to eclipse IDE. It worked :) Looks like using it as a hyperlink has issue.